# How to insert PDF file along with the app

Tags: java, android, file

I've got a question about files uploaded with app together.I need to create an app, for my company where they will store PDF files(By the click on the button, they can download a specific file).My question is: is there possibility to preload files together with app? Or I need server or something to store these files, and when somebody will click on specific button, it will request specific file from the server?

Comment: Please write some code sample.
Something you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Create a new folder in `project location/app/src/main` and rename it to `assets`.
Then copy your files there.

If you want to copy these files on runtime, use this method:

```
 private void copy(String fileName, String path) throws IOException {
       AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();

       InputStream in = assetManager.open(fileName);

       try {
           OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
           try {
               // Transfer bytes from in to out
               byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
               int len;
               while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                   out.write(buf, 0, len);
               }


               } finally {
                   out.close();
               }
           } finally {
               in.close();
               Log.d(TAG, "copy: successfully copied");
           }
       }
```